# Open outlook item

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How to open an Outlook entry programmatically using entry id?
I have the following code:

```
 Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set msg = olNS.GetItemFromID("entry id of an appointment/email")
```

Now how do I open the msg object inside Outlook?

Comment: I got it. It should be msg.Display. Adding it if this helps anyone in future.

Comment: If you put your comment in an answer and accept it, searchers from the future will know there is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

"It should be msg.Display" –  [Shibasis Sengupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576026/shibasis-sengupta)

Comment: Community wiki. Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.